# Why am I getting domainpark.cgi being called from my website?

Tags: page-speed, parking

I used to test my site on `www.exampleone.com` and now I have moved to the real domain `www.realdomain.com` now and `www.exampleone.com` is now parked by 1and1 (default). Now when I test to see which requests are made by the `www.realdomain.com`I see `domainpark.cgi` and `park.js` from Sedo Parking also being requested as well as the js that serves the ads by adclicks. How do I get rid of this?

It's not on the index page at all, and it's causing a lot of strain and slowing my site down.

Comment: are you doing the tests in your local machine with a local url or using a real url?. Have you checked your hosts file?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the quickest way is to look for "exampleone.com" in your source files (assuming you didn't do anything crazy like saving this names in DB or obfuscated them). Utilities like grep can be very useful for this. Once you found where they are you could do something about it.

Comment: The thing is it's not in the source file I've searched and i havent put it in the db or obfuscated it at all. Not sure what to do now.

Comment: First search the html as delivered to the browser.  If exampleone is not there, then search for it in *all* files that exist on your realdomain host, not just the page directly requested by your URL.  It's most likely in some auxilliary file somewhere like a .js file.

Comment: I will check that thanks, have never used grep can i do it with that?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by this - grep is a unix program, once you downloaded your source files you can use the program to look into the source files files ( grep -snr "exampleone\.com" mysourcedirectory/). There are alternatives for Windows as well.

Comment: you can use any tool you like. Many text editors have the option to search in files, if you don't have one, you can find many on Internet, but to help you with that. Geany is a free, simple and powerful one.

Comment: Text editors can usually search one file by one. Utilities like grep can search through the whole filesystem (assuming you have the right priviledges).